# SwiftUI: Real device shows strange behavior with asynchronous flow, while Simulator runs perfectly

Tags: swiftui

*** EDIT 23.20.20 ***

Due to the strange behavior discovered after my original post, I need to completely rephrase my question. I meanwhile re-wrote large parts of my code as well.

The issue:
I run an asynchronous HTTP GET search query, which returns me an Array `searchResults`, which I store in an ObservedObject `FoodDatabaseResults`.

```
struct FoodItemEditor: View {
    //...
    @ObservedObject var foodDatabaseResults = FoodDatabaseResults()
    @State private var activeSheet: FoodItemEditorSheets.State?
    //...
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        HStack {
                            // Name
                            TextField(titleKey: "Name", text: $draftFoodItem.name)
                            
                            // Search and Scan buttons
                            Button(action: {
                                if draftFoodItem.name.isEmpty {
                                    self.errorMessage = NSLocalizedString("Search term must not be empty", comment: "")
                                    self.showingAlert = true
                                } else {
                                    performSearch()
                                }
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").imageScale(.large)
                            }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                            //...
                        }
                        //...
                    }
                    //...
                }
            }
            //...
        }
        .sheet(item: $activeSheet) {
            sheetContent($0)
        }
    }
    
    private func performSearch() {
        UserSettings.shared.foodDatabase.search(for: draftFoodItem.name) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let networkSearchResults):
                guard let searchResults = networkSearchResults else {
                    return
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.foodDatabaseResults.searchResults = searchResults
                    self.activeSheet = .search
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                debugPrint(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func sheetContent(_ state: FoodItemEditorSheets.State) -> some View {
        switch state {
        case .search:
            FoodSearch(foodDatabaseResults: foodDatabaseResults, draftFoodItem: self.draftFoodItem) // <-- I set a breakpoint here
        //...
        }
    }
}

class FoodDatabaseResults: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedEntry: FoodDatabaseEntry?
    @Published var searchResults: [FoodDatabaseEntry]?
}
```

I get valid search results in my `performSearch` function. The `DispatchQueue.main.async` closure makes sure to perform the update of my `@Published var searchResults` in the main thread.

I then open a sheet, displaying these search results:

```
struct FoodSearch: View {
    @ObservedObject var foodDatabaseResults: FoodDatabaseResults
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    //...
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                if foodDatabaseResults.searchResults == nil {
                    Text("No search results (yet)")
                } else {
                    ForEach(foodDatabaseResults.searchResults!) { searchResult in
                        FoodSearchResultPreview(product: searchResult, isSelected: self.selectedResult == searchResult)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Food Database Search")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                // Remove search results and close sheet
                foodDatabaseResults.searchResults = nil
                presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Cancel")
            }, trailing: Button(action: {
                if selectedResult == nil {
                    //...
                } else {
                    //... Do something with the result
                    
                    // Remove search results and close sheet
                    foodDatabaseResults.searchResults = nil
                    presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Select")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this on the Simulator, everything works as it should, see https://wolke.rueth.info/index.php/s/KbqETcDtSe4278d

When I run it on a real device with the same iOS version (14.0.1), the `FoodSearch` view first correctly displays the search result, but is then immediately called a second time with empty (nil) search results. You need to look very closely at the screen cast here and you'll see it displaying the search results for a very short moment before they disappear: https://wolke.rueth.info/index.php/s/9n2DZ88qSB9RWo4

When setting a breakpoint in the marked line in my `sheetContent` function, the `FoodSearch` sheet is indeed called twice on the real device, while it's only called once in the Simulator.

I have no idea what is going on here. Hope someone can help. Thanks!

*** ORIGINAL POST ***

I run an HTTP request, which updates a @Published variable `searchResults` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` closure:

```
class OpenFoodFacts: ObservableObject {
    @Published var searchResults = [OpenFoodFactsProduct]()
    // ...
    
    func search(for term: String) {
        let urlString = "https://\(countrycode)-\(languagecode).openfoodfacts.org/cgi/search.pl?action=process&search_terms=\(term)&sort_by=unique_scans_n&json=true"
        let request = prepareRequest(urlString)
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            guard error == nil else {
                debugPrint(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let openFoodFactsSearchResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(OpenFoodFactsSearchResult.self, from: data)
                    guard let products = openFoodFactsSearchResult.products else {
                        throw FoodDatabaseError.noSearchResults
                    }
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.searchResults = products
                        self.objectWillChange.send()
                    }
                } catch {
                    debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    
struct OpenFoodFactsSearchResult: Decodable {
    var products: [OpenFoodFactsProduct]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case products
    }
}

struct OpenFoodFactsProduct: Decodable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    // ...
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
        // ...
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

I call the `search` function from my view:

```
struct FoodSearch: View {
    @ObservedObject var foodDatabase: OpenFoodFacts
    // ...
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(foodDatabase.searchResults) { searchResult in
                    FoodSearchResultPreview(product: searchResult, isSelected: self.selectedResult == searchResult)
                }
            }
            // ...
        }
        .onAppear(perform: search)
    }
    
    private func search() {
        foodDatabase.search(for: draftFoodItem.name)
    }
}
```

My ForEach list will never update, although I have a valid searchResult set in my OpenFoodFacts observable object and also sent an `objectWillChange` signal. Any idea what I'm missing?

Funny enough: On the simulator it works as expected:
https://wolke.rueth.info/index.php/s/oy4Xf6C5cgrEZdK

On a real device not:
https://wolke.rueth.info/index.php/s/TQz8HnFyjLKtN74

Comment: you don't need `self.objectWillChange.send` it is send automatically whenever published property changed, but did you really got into there? did you debug?

Comment: Yes, I got into the closure. Funny enough: On the simulator it updates, on a real device not...

Comment: @Asperi, I added a manual refresh to my view, printing in addition the counts of my variable searchResults. In the simulator the result is 3, on my device 0. So it's actually not a SwiftUI Published issue, but the search results get lost somehow. I'm definitely assigning them... :-(